# Can a set be both open and closed in vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am a little confused since $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself is a closed set, its complement must be open. But the complement of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an empty set, which seems like both closed and open. Because I can't find any element in an empty set, the implication will be always true ($P\to Q$ is always true when $P$ is false). Are there other examples of both closed and open sets or am I wrong about an empty set being both closed and open?

Does a set need to be exclusively open or exclusively closed? That is, if a set is not open, then can I conclude it must be closed?

---

If I negate the definition of an open set, would it be '$\exists \epsilon>0$ such that I can't find $B_r(\mathbf{x}) \subseteq S$" ? Then does this mean the set $S$ must be a closed set?

Comment: In general, if a set is open, this not imply that the set is not closed. An example. Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the discrete topology, induced by the discrete metric, i.e., $\tau=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In this case, $\{x\}$ is an open set, and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\}$ is closed, but $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, then, is open and his complemente, $\{x\}$ is closed. Furthermore, in this topology, every is open and closed.

Comment: Empty sets are always open and closed. A set need not be open or closed. For example, consider the interval $(0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ with standard topology.

Comment: "Are there other examples of both closed and open sets "  Well R^n itself.  In the standard topology those are the only two that are both both there are oodles that are neither.  In other topologies, such as the discrete topology there are be more that are both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you care about Euclidean topology. So to answer your original question, there no subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are both open and closed (of course other than the trivial ones). This is due to the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected.

As for your second question, a subset $S$ is not open if there exists $x \in S$  such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \not\subset S$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. However, this does not mean that $S$ is closed.

Comment: I think that your definition of not open is incorrect. I think a correct version would be a set $S$ is not open if there exists $x \in S$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon(x)$ contains at least one member of $S^c$.

Answer (score 1):

The terms "open" and "closed" set, are not mutually exclusive. In any topological space $(X,\tau)$, the underlying set $X$ and the empty set $\emptyset$, are always -by definition- both open and closed.

On the other hand, there may be subsets of $X$, which are neither open nor closed:  For example consider $[0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$, in the usual metric topology of the real numbers.

Comment: There is a class of spaces, the so-called "door spaces" (which are pretty strange), that are defined by "every subset of $X$ is open or closed (or both). Not all subsets are true "doors" (a normal door could not be open *and* closed at the same time), like $\emptyset$ and $X$. But IRL sets are not like doors at all. So the open/closed terminology might be somewhat misleading to beginners in topology.